# Sourcemaps not mapping correctly except "entry" specified in webpack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, webpack, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0. If anyone wants to see detailed code or run it themselves, the code can be found here: https://github.com/jakelauer/BaseballTheater/tree/master/BaseballTheaterCore

My basic problem is that I'm expecting each generated `js` file in my project to have a sourcemap back to the original `.ts` or `.tsx` file. That is not working **except** for my `entry` file (`./ClientApp/boot.tsx`).

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                {
                    test: /\.scss/,
                    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
                },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
        ])
    }];
};
```

Based on my interpretation of this file and *limited* understanding of webpack, this should work. Each of my files does generated a .js.map file, and it appears to be referenced in the generated .js file. However, none of them actually load except the one for `boot.tsx` when debugging in Chrome.

An example of one of the `js` files in Chrome:

[image]

And that file does have the correct files to load:
[image]

When I open `main.js.map` in `/wwwroot/dist/` and Ctrl+F for `ts` inside there, I only find `boot.tsx` and none of the other .ts or .tsx files I would expect to find.

I am no webpack expert, so I'm not sure what else to do!

Comment: I'm no expert either but if you're specifically talking about [sourcemaps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/), I do see a `game_list.js.map`. I think the `*.js.map` file is the sourcemap. When your browser runs the `game_list.js` file, it will probably detect the `game_list.js.map` file and will show you the original source code when debugging in browser. can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @RicoKahler Yeah, so the browser is just getting one file: `main.js`, which is generated by webpack. Webpack has some black magic built into it that, when the browser loads it, splits it back out into the various files that were bundled together. That file is apparently not working with my TypeScript files. I wish I could be more informative, I'm hoping someone comes along who knows what to ask me to help me out!

Comment: I see you're using webpack 2. Maybe an upgrade to 3 or 4 would possible fix that but there are breaking changes so you might have to change a few things for the upgrade to work

Comment: @RicoKahler I updated to webpack 4 to see if that alone would solve the problem, but it doesn't seem to have done anything.

Comment: try settings the [`devtool` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) to `source-map` and you might have to `npm install --save-dev source-map-loader`

Comment: @RicoKahler I was able to get this fixed by using `source-map-loader` eventually. The key was that I was originally assigning `source-map-loader` to files with the `.map` extension. Once I set webpack to use `source-map-loader` for `.js` files, it worked. Feel free to post as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, we've come to the solution by:

1. upgrading to the newest webpack (v4 in this case) and
2. installing the source-map loader via `npm install --save-dev source-map-loader` and
3. setting  [`devtool: 'source-map'`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) in the `webpack.config.js`.

The [`source-map` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) tells webpack to emit a full separate source map file. This is from the webpack docs:

> `source-map` - A full SourceMap is emitted as a separate file. It adds a reference comment to the bundle so development tools know where to find it.